# ASP.NET Web API Controllers without System.Web.Http (Pluggable, Decoupled Architecture)

Tags: asp.net, .net, design-patterns, architecture, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a pluggable project framework using ASP.NET Web API. I have a lot of the guts figured out but I'm having a problem with one part of the architecture that I'm not fully sure how to decouple.

As a simplified example, I have the following:

- Service/Presentation Layer (simple Web API hosted project, very little inside this, and it's basically just a shell which handles hosting in IIS or self-hosted)
- Domain layer, with the core, domain-layer pieces of the project
- Services (N number of services, each with a reference to the Domain layer: think microservices). Currently, each of these Services *also* has a reference to ASP.NET Web API 2.1

Now, the Services all reference the Domain layer because it has interfaces, helpers, etc. But, the Domain layer also references stuff like ASP.NET Web API 2.1, and more. My idea was to have a base "BaseController" in the Domain that each of the Services' controllers could inherit from, and in turn would all necessarily inherit the wired-up stuff like Get(), Post(), etc. The problem is that I don't want each of these services to also have to reference ASP.NET Web API 2.1 and the other dependencies. I want them to be able to use them through abstractions without actually referencing them directly. In other words, I want looser coupling and want the Services to be able to live autonomously and independent of System.Web.Http. It would help me enforce unit testing and SOLID principles as the project grows.

Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach here, but maybe not. My main goal is to create a pluggable, microservices framework using ASP.NET Web API with each microservices living as an independent assembly. So if there's another recommended approach I'm all ears.

Hopefully this makes sense. Any pointers? For what it's worth, I'm quite familiar with concepts of design patterns and SOLID principles; just not sure how to string this all together while maintaining some of the automatic request handling that controllers provide natively.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intention is great, implementation not so much. What you is actually called Application Services, those are the services that implement the application use cases using the Domain. When saying you don't want to be coupled to System.Web.Http etc I think you want to say you don't want your app (especially the Domain) coupled to the WebApi framwork.

I think you've misunderstood what decoupling means. It's not really about one assembly not depending on another, is about not coupling your objects/layer to an implementation detail of other objects/layers. That's why the Domain should **never** know about controllers, WebApi, Mvc etc they aren't part of the Domain, they're part of the UI or public API.

Just the API layer (a name coincidence) should know about controllers and whatever framework you're using (incidentally WebApi),anything else only know about their concerns. So the API (uses) -> Application Layer -> Domain.

Having autonomous components is ok, but you really don't want just one assembly to handle everything. Keep things clean and have something like:

- MyFeature.ApplicationServices
- MyFeature.Domain
- MyFeature.Persistence
- even MyFeature.UIWidgets (Web/Wpf etc)

This is just a suggestion, the important thing is to keep the concerns separated.

Here's a bit of code

```
public class MyAppService 
{
       public void DoSmth(InputData data){}
}

public class MyApiController
{
     public MyApiController(MyAppService svc) { }

     public void Post(SomeModel model)
     {
        var svcInput=model.ToServiceInput();
        _svc.DoSmth(svcInput);
     }

}
```

Your app service gets an input model from the controller and uses that to do its job. The Service never knows about webApi or anything, only about the input model. And things are decoupled and easy to test.

Comment: This definitely makes sense. Thank you for the very detailed answer. I'm pretty familiar (from an academic standpoint) of the approach you described and have also heard it referred to also as an Orchestration layer (AppServices), if I'm not mistaken. I can definitely see how this works better. The main reason for this approach was to provide devs with the ability to create a "service" in as few lines as possible, hence the inheritance of a base ApiController. I'm probably just complicating it. And good point about the term "decoupling"; I was using it in a generic and confusing way. :)

Comment: That all said, can you envision a way that would help me achieve the goal of "super simple microservice creation"? In other words, I'd love devs to be able to create a new Class Library, create a Controller subclass, and automatically get the auto wiring of the Web API request handling? All without needing an explicit reference to System.Web.Http? I've figured out so many other components like runtime assembly loading and controller probing, but this part throws me for a bit of a loop. Many thanks again!